# explicitly using constructor call in main as a function call parameter

Tags: c++, constructor, temporary, most-vexing-parse

I am trying to understand how explicit constructor call in main works using the following code.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Dependency1
{
      bool init;
public:
  Dependency1() : init(true) {
    std::cout << "Dependency1 construction"
              << std::endl;
  }
  void print() const {
    std::cout << "Dependency1 init: "
              << init << std::endl;
  }



};


class Dependency2 {
   Dependency1 d1;
public:
   Dependency2(const Dependency1& dep1): d1(dep1){
     std::cout << "Dependency2 construction ";
     print();
   }
   void print() const { d1.print(); }
};

void test( const Dependency1& dd1)
{
    cout  << " inside Test \n";
    dd1.print();
}



int main()
{

    test(Dependency1());
    Dependency2 D1(Dependency1()); // this line does not work

    return 0;
}
```

Function **test** is being called where constructor **Dependency1()** is used as a function call instead of **Dependency1::Dependency1( )** and the code runs perfectly fine.

Now if I use similar concept to create an object D1 of Dependency2, it does not work. 
Seems I am doing something wrong here based on wrong understanding.

Need to know how the Compiler resolves Dependency1() call in main even if scope resolution is not used and why it does not work when I use it as a parameter in constructor of **Dependency2**

Thanks,
Anand

Answer (score 7):

> `test(Dependency1())`

This calls a function `test` and passes a temporary object of class `Dependency1`. Because the formal parameter in the definition of `test` is a reference to `const` and because temporaries can be bound to `const` references your code works.

> `Dependency2 D1(Dependency1()); // this line does not work`

This is called C++ most vexing parse. `D1` is interpreted as a function returning `Dependency2` and taking an argument a pointer to function returning `Dependency1`.

Try `Dependency2 D1((Dependency1()));` and see the change in output.

Note: Putting an extra pair of parenthesis would make the compiler treat `(Dependency1())` as an expression.

Comment: That's great. Thanks. Is there any other way to make compiler recognize D1 as object and not a function ?

Comment: So if my understang is write, the compiler treat Dependency2 D1 (Dependency1()) as a function declaration, and that is why this line did not execute.

Comment: @Anand : I have already suggested a method. Read the post again.

Comment: @Prasoon: A perfect answer from your side.

Answer (score 1):

Dependency1() creates a temporary object of type Dependency1, that is passed to function test.

Comment: thanks, But why it does not work when I use similar thing to create Dependency2 object.